# Android resizable layout for video conference with multiple videos

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, gridview

I am developing a video conference and would like to add dynamically the video renderers to screen and
each to be resized to fit the screen depending on how many are at the time.
I have tried with grid layout something like :

```
remoteRender = new SurfaceViewRenderer(activity);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.width = TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.height = TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.leftMargin = 10;
    params.rightMargin = 10;
    params.topMargin = 10;
    params.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    remoteRender.setLayoutParams(params);
    setupRenderer(remoteRender);
    gridLayout.addView(remoteRender);
```

but the renderers have different sizes and they are not split the same.
I would like to achieve something like : [image]

What is the best approach for this. I have looked for some examples for this online but found none.

Comment: have you found any workaround?

Comment: Did you find anything?